# Opencart 403 Forbidden when move on remote server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, opencart

After finishing development on local machine i move my opencart to remote server via FTP. When i try to visit `www.myshop.com` i get

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server.
>
> Apache/2.2.31 (FreeBSD) PHP/5.6.25 Server at biroelektronik.com Port
>   80

But when i try to access `www.myshop.com/upload` everythink work fantastic and site shop is showed!

Does i need to create specific `.htaccess` whitch will point to `upload` directory and how to crate it? Or is somthing other problem here?

Here is my dir (root) `public_html` where i put all files:
[image]

What i try:
I create in root dir `.htaccess` file with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ upload/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

But not working i dont know whay

Answer (score 0):

Move the contents of the "upload" directory to the root of your web server. When you access `www.myshop.com` there is not an `index.php` file for the request to default to so it tries to view the actual directory contents as a file browser of sorts. Due to obvious security reasons this is next to never enabled by a web host and so the host reports that you don't have permission to view it.

When you access `www.myshop.com/upload` in reality you are accessing `www.myshop.com/upload/index.php` so just be sure that OpenCart's `index.php` file is located in your root directory.